# How to install phantomjs in Meteorjs?

Tags: meteor, phantomjs

How to install phantomjs in Meteor js? 
I want to use in conjunction with Iago Spiderable.

```
o/s: Windows 7 64bit
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you add the directory where Phantom is installed to PATH

From the Meteor documentation:

> When a spider requests an HTML snapshot of a page the Meteor server runs the client half of the application inside phantomjs, a headless browser, and returns the full HTML generated by the client code.
>   ...
>   If you deploy your application with meteor bundle, you must install phantomjs (http://phantomjs.org) somewhere in your $PATH. If you use meteor deploy this is already taken care of.

[1]http://docs.meteor.com/#spiderable

Answer (score 1):

I would like to let you know that there is package available for meteor 
 
https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/phantomjs 
not sure if that is compatible with windows.